# Oauth 2.0 clarifications about grant_type, client_id e client_secret

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I need to implement Oauth 2.0 protocol.
I just want to know if the entire workflow is clear for me, and if I had misunderstood something I'd like you to help me.
This is what I understood:

1. A user, using my client app has to login into my system. He submits
   email and password (prevently signed up) to a server (maybe a
   servlet on Tomcat). This servlet validates his credentials, so gives
   him the grant_type, that in my case is "password" type (or
   credentials one?). [FIRST QUESTION: does the resource owner issues
   also CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET to the user? If so, how should I
   generate them? If not so, who gives these things to the user? Is the
   CLIENT_ID the same for every user using my app?  SECONDO QUESTION:
   the grant_type is just a string that show the type of grant
   (meaning: "password" or "credentials" or "implicit")?]
2. Now that the user gained the grant_type and have validated
   credentials, he needs an access_token and a refresh_token. He has to
   send grant_type, client_id and client_secret to the
   authentication_server (that wraps also the token_endpoint), and
   gives him the access_token and refresh_token. Now the user, when has
   to ask something to the resource_server provides the access_token
   and the refresh_token. If the access_token is expired, the
   resource_owner checks if the refresh_token is still valid, and
   generates another access_token. [THIRD QUESTION: why does the
   refresh_token is so useful? If a man in the middle stole the
   request, he will obtain the access_token and also the refresh_token,
   so although the access_token will expire, he can obtain others using
   the refresh_token, right? FOURTH QUESTION: does the user has to send
   ALWAYS the access_token when requestin somethign?]

Thanks to everyone. Have a good day. :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the OAuth2 flows and terminology seems to be a bit blurred. It doesn't make a lot of sense to explain it here to you, since this information is widely available. Try e.g. [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2).